# How can I discard the changes from a pending git commit?

Tags: git, github

I have 2 commits that haven't been pushed to the remote repo.

Commit A adds some files
Commit B removes the files

I want to remove Commit A as I'm unable to push it to the remote repo due to the file size (it times out). How can I remove Commit A?

I tried an interactive rebase but it didn't work when I deleted the Commit A line in the editor.

Comment: "_when I deleted the Commit A line in the editor_" do you mean you marked Commit A as `d`/`drop`, or did you literally just delete the line?

Comment: When I did the interactive rebase it opened up a text editor and I just removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI I resolved this by running the command:

git reset --mixed origin/master